# Getopts not working inside of function

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to use `getops` in a function yet it doesn't seem to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

function main()
{
  while getopts ":p:t:c:b:" o; do
    case "${o}" in
    p)
      echo "GOt P"
      p=$OPTARG
      ;;
    t)
      echo "GOt T"
      t=$OPTARG
      ;;
    c)
      echo "GOt C"
      c=$OPTARG
      ;;
    b)
      echo "GOt b"
      b=$OPTARG
      ;;
    *)
      #usage 
      echo "Unknown Option"
      return 
      ;;
      esac
  done

  echo $p
  echo $t
  echo $c
  echo $b
}

main
```

And then running it like this:

```
$ ./bin/testArguments.sh -p . -t README.md -c 234 -b 1
```

I have tried making sure that optid are local yet this didn't work either. Anything else that might be wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not passing any argument to your `main` function. If you want that function to get the same arguments as passed to the script, pass them along with:

```
main "$@"
```

Instead of:

```
main
```

Also relevant to your script:

- [difference between “function foo() {}” and “foo() {}”](/a/74045)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)
- you'd want to output errors on stderr: `echo >&2 Unknown option`
- you'd want to return a non-zero exit status upon error (`return 1`)
- when calling `getopts` in a function, it's a good habit to set `OPTIND` to 1 initially, in case `getopts` has been called before (for instance in a previous invocation of the function).

Comment: @Dean No, functions may have their own command line parsing.

Comment: It works, very good explanation, Thanks a ton. :)

Answer (score 1):

In a function, the parameters are those passed to the function, not those passed to the script:

```
$ cat foo.sh
function main ()
{
    echo "$@"
}

echo "$@"
main
$ bash foo.sh bar
bar

$
```

You need to pass `"$@"` to `main`:

```
main "$@"
```

Though I find a `main` function in scripts rather useless, unless you plain to call `main` again and again in the same script.